# How to load a PDf file with url in Xcode with Objective-C in a UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, url, pdf, uiwebview

I've a question in Objective-C, I'm working on an iOS application that display a PDF file from a website -box server- each file have a certain url, so would someone help me to show me (( How to load a PDf file with url in Xcode with Objective-C in a UIWebView ??))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy. Here is an example:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.catvets.com/public/PDFs/ClientBrochures/FriendsforLifeBrochure-Purina.pdf"]; 
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

When the HTML arrives, it will display in the `UIWebView`.